# How to write: "submit to review" or "submit for review"?

Tags: prepositions

How to say more correctly: "to submit to review" or "to submit for review"?

Ngrams says that "submit for review" is more frequent usage. But I still see a lot of "Submit to review" in software related topics.

Could you help and say is it correct to use "submit to review" phrase or this is completely incorrect?

Comment: What is the context?  Can you provide a complete sentence where you would use this phrase?  Why do you think _to review_ is better than _for review_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Submit for review" certainly sounds more familiar to me.

"Submit to review" is possible, but there is a distinct phrasal verb "submit to", which means "acknowledge that somebody else has the power or authority over one", which gets in the way of interpretation.

To clarify:

- *Submit* (intransitive) and *Submit [oneself] to somebody* mean this "put oneself in somebody else's power.
- *Submit something [to somebody]* means "put the something in somebody else's power, usually for them to review or judge it". *For review* is not an essential part, but just explaining the purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I understood that "Submit to <someone> for review" will sound perfect, right?
But can I short the phrase to "Submit to review" with keeping the same meaning?

Comment: You can, but it will sound odd. Either omit the "to" phrase (_Submit for review_) or include the direct object as well (_Submit the report to X for review_).

Answer (score 0):

Submit to review may be correct if you write "submit to Review" where "Review" is a colloquially known title for a review committee in an institution.

Comment: I think that if you are using a "to" phrase in that meaning, you really need a direct object (the thing being submitted) as well.